# CSS - context used styling?

Tags: css

I thought that it was possible, but everyone tells me it's not.

I want context styling in my css file like:

```
div#foo {
 h2 {
   color: #F42
 }
 p.bar {
   font-size: 12px
 }
}
```

So that only h2 and p.bar in the div with id foo will be styled. Or is this only possible with LESS and other similar libs?

Thanks & kind regards,
Jurik

Comment: You cannot nest CSS declarations like that. They are not valid. Yup, you need LESS to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with pure CSS, that's why you should use [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) (i suggest to use SASS/SCSS), which are CSS supersets

LESS/SASS-SCSS allows you to write dynamic CSS with ease, take a look at [this](http://wrangl.com/sass-v-less) comparision

check out [COMPASS](http://compass-style.org/) which is the main reason why I suggest you SASS/SCSS

Comment: There's even a .NET port of LESS called dotless i just plugged it into a project and got it working in under 2 minutes! No client-side code needed

Comment: nice! SASS/COMPASS comes with default server-side auto-compilation (you just specify the folder to watch and where to deploy) ;D I dunno... i really don't like JS compilation with less (and most of all the lack of compass) :\

Comment: Thanks alot - I heard that it's still in CSS3 not possible... blame wc3 :S

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with standard css, the 2 classes would need to be set like:

```
div#foo h2 {}
div#foo p.bar {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but as follows:

```
div#foo h2 {
    /* styles go here */
}

div#foo p.bar {
    /* styles go here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have above is just a slightly altered version of:

```
div#foo h2 { color: #F42; }
div#foo p.bar { font-size: 12px }
```

I don't really see any gain to it.

Comment: When you got CSS files with over 2.000 lines, you'd see the gain in using contextes - a better overview for the engineer and less code.

Comment: @Jurik: I have css files with that much bulk, and simple organization keeps everything in its place, easy to find. The only real gain to be had would be the minification of repetitive selectors, but on a standard web page viewable on a pc browser this is a minimal gain. If the target audience is mobile (where such a gain would be seen), I would say mistake #1 is having a design that requires a css file with 2k lines.

Answer (score 0):

[Less](http://lesscss.org/) let's you do pretty much what you described, as well as some other cool stuff like use variables in css etc.

Of course, once you let it compile, it'll just turn it into the valid CSS that has been suggested in the previous answers. Still worth a look IMHO.

Comment: Yeah and there's the problem... well - at least it's easier to script for the engineer - but still large CSS output after it is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

yes but separated...

```
div#foo h2 {
   color: #F42
 }
div#foo p.bar {
   font-size: 12px
 }
```

but I would like too change a bit:

```
#foo h2 {
   color: #F42
 }
#foo p.bar {
   font-size: 12px
 }
```

you are using an ID so you don't need to say nothing before because ID's are unique

Comment: They're unique per HTML page, but this CSS may be used over multiple pages where `foo` could be the id of another element.

Comment: yes but what I was saying was that it can't have, for example, a `span#foo` and `div#foo`

Comment: Thanks, but main focus was on the possibility of using context in css - and now I know it's not possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible using default CSS techniques.

But, by using [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [less](http://lesscss.org/) however, it is possible.

The code in your question, works in both of the libraries above.